# Как задать цвет фона текста в IText

Tags: c#, itext

Мне нужно задать цвет фона выбранного текста.
Я знаю, как сформировать прямоугольник, в котором будет находиться этот текст.
Если я задам цвет для этого прямоугольника и заполню его, текст не будет виден.
Можно ли как-то нарисовать прямоугольник так, чтобы текст был виден или есть какой-то другой путь?

```
PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
            canvas.SetLineWidth(1);
            canvas.Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
            canvas.SetFillColor(iText.Kernel.Colors.DeviceRgb.GREEN);
            canvas.Fill();
            canvas.ClosePathStroke();
```

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался. Нужно добавить PdfTextMarkupAnnotation на эту область.

```
float[] quads = new float[8];
            quads[0] = rect.GetX();
            quads[1] = rect.GetY() + rect.GetHeight();
            quads[2] = rect.GetX() + rect.GetWidth();
            quads[3] = quads[1];
            quads[4] = quads[0];
            quads[5] = rect.GetY();
            quads[6] = quads[2];
            quads[7] = quads[5];
PdfTextMarkupAnnotation highlightAnnotation = 
    PdfTextMarkupAnnotation.CreateHighLight(rect, quads);
//установка цвета аннотации
highlightAnnotation.SetColor(ColorConstants.GREEN);
page.AddAnnotation(highlightAnnotation);
```

Возможно кому-нибудь это пригодится.